# recorrer json desde php

Tags: php, jquery, json

Construyo mi json desde php

```
        $marcas   = $this->MainModel->getmarcas();  
        $valores = array();
        foreach ($marcas as $value) {
            $Where["id_marca"] = $value->id_marca;
            $valores[] = $this->MainModel->getvalores($Where);
        }

        $this->output
                    ->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_output(
                        json_encode(array(
                            'success'=>true,
                            'valores'=>$valores
                        ))  
        );
```

Quedando de esta forma :

> creo que se puede deber a que tengo un [] que es el uso para insertar
>   los datos del foreach

```
{
  "success": true,
  "valores": [
    [
      {
        "valor1": "1231",
        "valor2": "345"
      },
      {
        "valor1": "45345",
        "valor2": "435"
      },
      {
        "valor1": "4535",
        "valor2": "34"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

He intentado hacerlo de esta forma sin resultados:

```js
var valores = {
  "success": true,
  "series": [
    [
      {
        "valor1": "1231",
        "valor2": "345"
      },
      {
        "valor1": "45345",
        "valor2": "435"
      },
      {
        "valor1": "4535",
        "valor2": "34"
      }
    ]
  ]
};

$.each(valores, function(index, element) {
    console.log(element[index].valor1); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Si haces un `console.log(valores)` como aparece? y dentro del bucle `console.log(index, element)`?

Comment: me retorna undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu JSON, `valores` es un array que contiene otro array que a su vez contiene los pares { valor1, valor2 }. Prueba recorriéndolo así:

```
// Esto hace la iteración sobre el array "exterior"
$.each(valores, function(i, eli){ 
    // Esto itera sobre el array "interior"
    $.each(eli, function(j, elj){ 
        alert(elj.valor1); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: gracias no sabia como podia acceder al elemento.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes porque tu variable valores es un texto plano en formato `json`, lo cual para poder recorrerlo desde `javascript`, debes utilizar `parseJSON` en el caso de que estés implementando `jquery`.

Para implementarlo, seria de la siguiente manera:

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON( valores);
 $.each(json.valores, function(index, element) {
     alert(element.valor1); 
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

Intenta con un simple `for` de la siguiente manera:

```
for(var i in data.valores.items) {
    console.log("Valor 1: "data.valores.items[i].valor1 +" Valor2: "+data.valores.items[i].valor1);  
}
```